# How do I change the style of the cursor with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse-cursor

I want to change the style of the cursor as if it were going over a link. How do I do this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Modify the CSS `cursor` value by using the `css()` method

```
$('#selector').css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/H6Nta/

Answer (score 9):

you can play around with this

```
$('#divid').css('cursor','default');
```

for pointer

```
$('#divid').css('cursor','pointer');
```

api

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 7):

using css

http://www.echoecho.com/csscursors.htm

read here for different  cursor styles

and apply it

```
$('#selector').css('cursor', 'value');
```

Answer (score 3):

Cursors are handled by CSS. You need something like

```
$('#elementid').css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

or for old IE browsers

```
$('#elementid').css('cursor', 'hand');
```