# What code is required to swap a javascript variable (trailimage) to another when clicking within a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, variables, cursor

When clicking (onmousedown or onclick) for example, I would like to change the variable of the trailimge in the javascript to another image. You see, I have an image (a hand) that is following the cursor coordinates. I am unable to code and change the current image to swap to another trailimage after clicking. I will also need to find a way of reverting to the original trailimage when unclicking. The affect will seem as though the handis tapping or pointing.

```
var trailimage=["images/contact/gardening-glove-cursor.png", , ]
```

I believe the answer may be within some form of swap variable scripting

e.g.

```
var a = 1,
b = 2;

var foo = 1;
var bar = 2;
foo = [bar, bar = foo][0];
```

**Trailimage javascript excerpts**

```
var trailimage=["images/contact/gardening-glove-cursor.png", , ]
var offsetfrommouse=[-110,5]
var displayduration=0

if (document.getElementById || document.all)
document.write('<div id="trailimageid" style="position:absolute;visibility:visible;left:0px;top:100px;width:1px;height:1px"><img border="0" src="'+trailimage[0]+'"></div>')

function followmouse(e){
var xcoord=offsetfrommouse[0]
var ycoord=offsetfrommouse[1]
if (typeof e != "undefined"){
xcoord+=e.pageX
ycoord+=e.pageY
}

</script>
```

Comment: function .onmousedown ()     { var trailimage=["images/contact/gardening-glove-cursor_click.png", , ]    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/33n2t6ov/)

```js
var trailimage = ["http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130626213446/elderscrolls/images/2/2d/TES3_Morrowind_-_Glove_-_Black_Left_Glove.png",
            "http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130626213454/elderscrolls/images/9/91/TES3_Morrowind_-_Glove_-_Black_Right_Glove.png"]
$(function() {
  $(".logo").attr("src",trailimage[0]);
  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    $('.logo').offset({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY + 20
    });
  });
    $(document).on("mousedown",function() {
         $(".logo").attr("src",trailimage[1]);   
    })
    $(document).on("mouseup",function() {
         $(".logo").attr("src",trailimage[0]);   
    })
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="logo" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png" alt="glove" />
```

Comment: Right, hello. Thankyou very much. This is is functioing perfectly, however, at the moment, it is a static image div that does not follow the cursor.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your "however". Do you have other requirements?

Comment: Well, this image is a trailimage, that follows the cursor. It is a static div image. I am not sure how to code the mouse responsive image to continue following the cursor.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you are trying to do

Comment: http://deverexdrawer.deviantart.com/art/Trailimage-538913342                                                                                                   As you can see in this image, the trailimage is static on the page (within a div) and won't move. The trailimage is following the cursor as well. There are duplicates. The static trailimage clicks. But the trailimage that follows the cursor doesn't. How would I be able to have the static trailimage folow the cursor.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/SYwba/light/ This is the closest example I can find on the web. So the image must follow the cursor and swap variable to another image to look as though the hand image is clicking.

Comment: I see that you cannot click on the image since it is trailing... See update

Comment: Thankyou. Your answer has contibuted to the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Possible Duplicate [How do I change the style of the cursor with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932837/how-do-i-change-the-style-of-the-cursor-with-jquery)

you can specify like

```
$('#trailimageid').css('cursor', 'url(' + trailimage[i] + ')');
```

assuming i as array index